# Array to multiply to the power of 3

Tags: arrays, vb.net

The following code loads an array and multiplies to the power of 2

```
Sub Main()

    Console.WriteLine("-EXAMPLE-" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine)

    Dim array(24) As Double, i As Long

    array(0) = 1
    For i = 1 To 24
        array(i) = 2 * array(i - 1)
    Next i
    Call DisplayArray(array)
End Sub
Sub DisplayArray(ByRef array() As Double)
    Dim i As Long, n As Long

    n = array.GetLength(0)
    For i = 0 To n - 1
        Console.WriteLine(array(i) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine)
    Next i
End Sub
```

How can I adjust the code to make it to the power of 3?

I have changed the value '2' to '3' but still no luck

Comment: what is the issue you are getting when you change from 2 to 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an impression that you wanted to numbers that are powers of 3, if that is the case the elements in your array would be 1, 3, 9, 27, 81 etc., (powers of 3) if that is the case below logic should work.

```
    array(0) = 1
    For i = 1 To 24
        array(i) = 3 * array(i - 1)
    Next i
```

Alternatively you can also do like this...

```
    For i = 0 To 24
        array(i) = Math.Pow(3, i)
    Next i
```

However if you are expecting your array to be filled by 1, 3, 6, 9, etc., (multiples of 3) then below code should work.

```
    array(0) = 1
    For i = 1 To 24
        array(i) = 3 * i
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

like this
**imports system.math**

```
Sub Main()

    Console.WriteLine("-EXAMPLE-" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine)

    Dim array(24) As Double, i As Long

    array(0) = 1
    For i = 1 To 24
        array(i) = Math.Pow(3, array(i-1))
    Next i
    Call DisplayArray(array)
End Sub
Sub DisplayArray(ByRef array() As Double)
    Dim i As Long, n As Long


    For i = 0 To array.count-1
        Console.WriteLine(array(i) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I think what LyanR wants is to have elements to be multiples of three, but your code will not work the way he wanted.

Comment: Nah, array(0) = 1 hence array(1) will be 1^3 = 1, and all elements will be 1 only.

Comment: what is your ouput like 1,3,27 like this